# Chrome extension get Cookie when "change site data"

Tags: cookies, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Regarding getting Cookie from my chrome extension, it works perfectly when the chrome setting "On all sites".

But when I set "On [current site]" or "When you click the extension" in chrome extension setting, I couldn't get any cookies..

https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en
"Let extensions read and change site data"

※ When I keep opening the url where I want to get the cookie, it's success...

I tried to look for the solution, but there were nothing.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "cookies"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [ "https://wanna-get-cookie-this-domain.com/*" ],
  "background": { "service_worker": "service_worker.js" },
  "content_scripts": [
     {
       "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
       "matches": ["https://*/*"]
     }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 3
}
```

service_woeker.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "testapp",
  title: "title",
  contexts: ["all"],
  type: "normal"
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: `/views/popup.html`,
    type: 'popup',
    focused: true,
    width: 395, height: 230
  });
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type == "getCookie") {
    chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
      console.log(cookies);
      // "On all sites" works. 
      // "On [current site]" or "When you click the extension" doesn't work 
      // even after I clicked and enabled the extension.
    });
  }

  return true;
});
```

views/popup.html

```
<html>
 ...
<script src="/scripts/popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

scripts/popup.js

```
// After user clicked, below code
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'getCookie'}));
```

Thanks,

Comment: In that mode the access is provided only after the user interacts with your extension.

Comment: Thanks. Even after user clicked and enabled the extension, I cannot get any cookies..

Comment: I added manifest.json and my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://crbug.com/1257916#c12):

> the `cookies` API is only checking the host permissions, and not checking tab-specific permissions, since the request isn't associated with a tab.

Until it's fixed you'll have add the host permissions for all sites in manifest.json:

```json
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
```

Note that your content script already runs on all https sites (why not all sites though?), which means that your extension is already requesting the "broad host permission" under the hood, so adding the same pattern to `host_permissions` doesn't increase the internal permissions of your extension, it's more of a cosmetic requirement to allow the use of `chrome` API in the non-content scripts like the background script.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see. I gave up implementing this.

Comment: Facing the same issue and have to give up after seeing that it is a bug